# Simple node.js function return undefined instead of Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function

I am learning nodejs and i am having some issues with a simple function.
This function just have to create an array, the problem i have is that when the array have more than one item and i try to assigne the result in another variable the variable is always undefined. Does someone know why is this happening and what am I doing wrong ?

```
var readline = require("readline-sync");

function userTabCreation_stringList(inUserList = [])
{
    inUserList.push(readline.question("Veuillez entrer le nom du premier utilisateur : "));
    if (readline.question("Voulez vous ajouter un utilisateur supplementaire ? (Y/y : yes)").toUpperCase() === "Y")
    {
        userTabCreation_stringList(inUserList);
    }else
    {
        console.log(inUserList) // the array has no probleme here and is ok
        return inUserList;
    }
}

//Main

userList = userTabCreation_stringList();
console.log(userList); // My Array is shown as undefined when i have more than one item
```

I know i can developed this differently but i really want to understand why this function is not working.

Thanks for your time and your answer

Comment: What is the output of `readline.question(...)`

Comment: readline.question is the methode i used to get an input from the commandLine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the result of your recursive function call:

```
if (readline.question("Voulez vous ajouter un utilisateur supplementaire ? (Y/y : yes)").toUpperCase() === "Y")
{
   return userTabCreation_stringList(inUserList);
} else {
   ...
}
```

Otherwise you will return nothing if you add more than one item.